# FPS Problem. Can't run 60 FPS intro (youtube intro)

Tags: animation

How come when blender is done rendering my intro in 60 fps, when i run it in any video player it is choppy. The intro is 10 seconds and it says it is ten seconds but lags and takes longer to get through the intro? I'm not professional so try to answer simply please.

Comment: It means that your computer is not fast enough to sustain that playrate.